# Representación textual del atributo de un objeto

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Digamos que tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "Objeto {} y {}".format(self.a, self.b)
```

La forma para obtener una representación textual de ese objeto es utilizando el método `__str__`

Pero si además yo deseo  obtener la representación textual de sus atributos, por ejemplo, si yo hago esto:

```
>>> test = Test(4, 5)
>>> print(test)
'Objeto 4 y 5'
>>> print(test.a + test.b)
9
>>> print(test.a)
'Atributo a: 4'
>>> print(test.b)
'Atributo b: 5'
```

¿Qué opciones tengo para realizar algo como esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues no se si sea posible conseguir lo que quieres, por lo menos no con una sola clase. El método [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) retorna la representación del objeto, no de los atributos. Por supuesto que es perfectamente posible formatear el objeto de tal manera que se muestren sus atributos como lo muestras en tu ejemplo:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Objeto {} y {}".format(self.a, self.b)
```

Creo que podrías conseguir lo que quieres usando una clase más que represente los enteros. Algo como esto:

```
class Number():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.number + other.number

    def __str__(self):
        return "Atributo: {}".format(self.number)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.number


class Test():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = Number(a)
        self.b = Number(b)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Objeto {} y {}".format(self.a.__repr__(), self.b.__repr__())
```

Si reproducimos tus pruebas:

```
>>> test = Test(4,5)
>>> print(test)
'Objeto 4 y 5'
>>> print(test.a + test.b)
9
>>> print(test.a)
'Atributo: 4'
>>> print(test.b)
'Atributo: 5'
```

Recuerda que en Python los enteros también son objetos. Al hacer `"Objeto {} y {}".format(self.a, self.b)` en realidad estás llamando a los métodos `int.__str__()` de `a` y `b`:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> '{}'.format(n)
'10'
>>> n.__str__()
'10'
>>> '{}'.format(n) == n.__str__()
True
```

Dicho esto, tranquilamente la clase `Numero` podría heredar directamente de `int` y ahorrarnos algunas definiciones. Solo necesitamos sobreescribir el método `__str__()` para que se muestre como tu quieres:

```
class Number(int):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "Atributo: {}".format(self.number)
```

Comment: Estaba pensando la posibilidad de algo más simple. Porque por ejemplo si quiero realizar otras operaciones (multiplicación, división, etc) tendría que sobreescribir todos esos métodos y se me agrega mucho código. Por ahora solo se me ocurre añadir otro atributo con otro nombre que tenga el formato que quiero algo como `self._fmt_a = "Atributo: {}".format(self.a)`.

Comment: @JavierCárdenas es por eso que en ultimo ejemplo heredo de `int` para no tener que lidiar con operaciones aritméticas

Comment: Si tienes razón no había leído con calma esa parte.

Comment: Si bien es cierto que `"{}".format(obj)` invoca al método `obj.__str__`, no es recomendable usar la *representación* del objeto `obj.__repr__` para componer cadenas. Es mejor cambiar el formato. El resultado de `Test.__str__` se podría reescribir así: `"Objeto {:d} y {:d}".format(self.a, self.b)`.